# Check contains condition conditionally by dataframe index in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to conditionally check in a pandas dataframe if a string value contains some other string values, defined as a regex. The string values to check for change per row, and right now are stored in a series, with the formats displayed below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["a", "a", "b", "c", "de", "de"], columns=["Value"])

df:
| Index   | Value   |
|   0     | "a"     |
|   1     | "a"     |
|   2     | "b"     |
|   3     | "c"     |
|   4     | "de"    |
|   5     | "de"    |

series = pd.Series(["a|b|c", "a", "d|e", "c", "c|a", "f|e"])

Series with contains regex per row:
| Index   | Value   |
|   0     | "a|b|c" |
|   1     | "a"     |
|   2     | "d|e"   |
|   3     | "c"     |
|   4     | "c|a"   |
|   5     | "f|e"   |

Expected output of contains:
[True, True, False, True, False, True]
```

If I were doing an .isin() and only needed to check for an exact match of some values, I could simply do the following:

```
Series with isin list per row:
| Index   | Value   |
|   0     | [a, b]  |
|   1     | [a]     |
|   2     | [d, e]  |
|   3     | [c]     |
|   4     | [c, a]  |
|   5     | [d, e]  |

dataframe["value"].isin(series)
```

since each row would be mapped to the right list to check by index by default

However, I need to check whether any of those values are contained, they do not need to be an exact match, so I need to use contains. I keep getting a "Series is not hashable" error when trying to do this:

`dataframe["value"].str.lower().str.contains(series)`

And I am not sure how could I make the contains function map to the actual regex to check per row. I would like to avoid lambdas and apply as much as possible, since I am processing a big dataset and I need execution to be as performant as possible

Thanks for the help,

Comment: please edit you question to provide the output of `dataframe.to_dict()` and `series.to_dict()` for reproducibility, and the **explicit** expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a loop/list comprehension here:

```
import re
out = [bool(re.search(pat, s)) for pat, s in zip(series, df['Value'])]

# or as new column in df:
# df['new'] = [bool(re.search(pat, s)) for pat, s in zip(series, df['Value'])]
```

output: `[True, True, False, True, False, True]`

Comment: This works, thanks! If I later wanted to use this boolean list as a dataframe mask, to index only True columns, do you know which type of transform should I do? Creating a Series out of it is giving me a "Unalignable boolean Series provided as  indexer" error

Comment: you should be able to directly use `df[out]`. If you have a *"Unalignable boolean Series*" error, this means the Series is likely shorter. What is the output of `len(series), len(df)`?